# How to update multiple rows with multiple values?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-update, inner-join, bulk

Well, I have a table as this

```
id       | idtable2|value   | code   |name       |
1        |     3   |983     |  10    |Total      |
2        |     4   |89      |  10    |type 4     |
3        |     5   |299     |  10    |type 5     |
4        |     6   |0       |  10    |type 6     |
5        |     7   |72      |  10    |type 7     |
6        |     8   |523     |  10    |type 8     |
7        |     4   |        |  11    |percentaje4|
8        |     5   |        |  11    |percentaje5|
9        |     6   |        |  11    |percentaje6|
10       |     7   |        |  11    |percentaje7|
11       |     8   |        |  11    |percentaje8|
```

where I have my values and I need to have theirs percentages.
These percentajes are based on  values you could see.
To get for example my rows with id 7 i could do it

```
declare @total int
set @total=(select value from table where name='total')
update table set value=(select value from table where code=1' and name='type 4')/@total
```

and I'll need do it for all my rows which are percentages, but this is a dinamic table.
In another table I have a id, and a name (`table1.name it's equals to table2.name`)
and table1 for every code (10,11) is going to have a name (from table2)

How can I get this values? I tried with a query as it.

```
update ce set valor=valor/@total from #table1 ce inner join table2 m
on ce.t2id=m.id 
where codigo=10
```

but i got it update values with code 10, and not values with code 11.
How could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple values in the where clause, by using IN:

```
update ce set valor=valor/@total from #table1 ce inner join table2 m
on ce.t2id=m.id 
where codigo in (10, 11)
```

Comment: no, valor where codigo is 11 is takes from valor (value) where codigo is 10

Answer (score 0):

Remove the where clause and it's done:

```
update ce set valor=valor/@total from #table1 ce inner join table2 m
on ce.t2id=m.id
```

You don't have to specify anything :)

Comment: no, where code is 11, value will be taken where value(valor) is 10

Answer (score 0):

If you join #table1 to itself on idTable2 and filter one with codigo = 10 and the other with codigo = 11, you can use valor from codigo = 10 to calculate percentage of codigo = 11.

```
update ce11 
   set valor=ce10.valor/@total 
from #table1 ce11 
  inner join #table1 ce10 
     on ce11.idTable2 = ce10.idTable2
    and ce11.codigo = 11
    and ce10.codigo = 10
```